# Adjust line height of a text field with a fixed font size

Tags: android

I have a textfield which whose font size for eg, is `14sp`. Can I set the text field's line height to be a fixed value, like maybe `18dp`? I cant seem to find a way to do this in android

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
android:textSize="18dp"
```

Use this in your xml layout file where you declare the `TextView`.

Comment: Nope. Text size sets the size of the font. I'm talking about the entire line height which includes some padding on all sides of the text

Comment: Can't you set android:layout_height="18dp"? Or, if the textview has some vertical padding, you could set layout_height to 18dp+totalVerticalPadding.

Comment: Its a multiline text field, so it'd have to be padding for each line. Wouldn't padding just add height all round?